# Tensorflow Shape of a vector is (col,)

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, python-3.5, linear-regression

I have been working through Andrew Ng's course lately, and I figured I might as well try to implement what I've learnt in other languages (which so happens to be Python for me), but I've run into a wall.
Here's my code:

```
train_x = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]]
train_y = [24, 1680]

train_x = np.asarray(train_x)
train_y = np.asarray(train_y)

m = train_x.shape[0]
n = train_x.shape[1]

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n])

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(n, 1))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(1, 1))

model = tf.add(tf.multiply(X, W), b)
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(model-Y, 2)) / (2*m)
```

And then I train a GradientDescentOptimizer using:

```
for i in range(1000):
    for x, y in zip(train_x, train_y):
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x, Y: y})
```

The error I'm getting is (on that last line):

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (4,) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 4)'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Explanations are even better.

Comment: That's not a row vector; it's just a vector. It's 1-dimensional.

Comment: Editted, thanks! Just to confirm, is something that looks like: [1,2,3,4] not a row vector?

Comment: Yeah, that's not a row vector. [[1, 2, 3, 4]] would be a row vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reshape input `x` to `(some_number, 4)` . Also fix the `y` placeholder

```
train_x = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
train_y = [24, 1680]

train_x = np.asarray(train_x)
train_y = np.asarray(train_y)

m = train_x.shape[0]
n = train_x.shape[1]

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((n, 1)))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(1, 1))

model = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, W), b)
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(model - Y, 2)) / (2 * m)

...
for i in range(1000):
    for x, y in zip(train_x, train_y):
        x = np.reshape(x, (-1, 4))
        y = np.reshape(y, (-1, 1))
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x, Y: y})
```

Comment: Thanks! Got quite a bit further than before, but now there seems to be another issue.
Incompatible shapes: [2,4] vs. [2] on the cost line.
I assume this is due to the model-Y part?

Comment: I've actually done both of those, and the issue still persists.

Comment: I had tried that before. Here's what that's giving me: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,4], [4].

Comment: See my updated answer, the another error was due to shape of `W`

Comment: That worked perfectly. Now it's time to skim over tensorflow's source to figure out exactly what that's doing, but I should be able to work through that myself. Thanks!